# Copy If statement from single cell to all cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

i have been able to use the below code in order to input either "Print Documents" or "E-Delivery" into cell K2 using an If/Else statement.  I am looking to try to extend this same statement for all of Column K (i.e K3 searching O3 and returning the correct value). Any help would be much appreciated.
many thanks,
Michael

```
Sub InsertType()

Dim score As Integer, result As String
score = Range("O2").Value

If score > 0 Then
    result = "Print Documents"
Else
    result = "E-Delivery"
End If

Range("K2").Value = result

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use a formula? `=IF(O2>0,"Print Documents","E-Delivery")`.

Comment: You could just put in cell K2 `=IF(O2>0,"Print Documents","E-Delivery")` and then fill it down the page. Even if you're determind to use VBA to avoid having formulae on the sheet, the best way is to fill the range with the formula `Range("O2:O10").Formula = "=IF(O2>0,""Print Documents"",""E-Delivery"")"` and then convert it to value `Range("O2:O10").Value = Range("O2:O10").Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop your VBA code :)

**Code:**

```
Sub InsertType()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim score As Integer, result As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name of worksheet

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in column O



For i = 1 To lRow 'Loop from row 1 to last row
score = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, "O"), ws.Cells(i, "O")).Value 'Take value from row i and column O

If score > 0 Then
    result = "Print Documents"
Else
    result = "E-Delivery"
End If

ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, "K"), ws.Cells(i, "K")).Value = result 'Print Result in Row i and column K
Next i

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: `ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, "K"), ws.Cells(i, "K")).Value = result ` - the duplicate `Cells` call seems a bit redundant, right? Same for `score = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, "O"), ws.Cells(i, "O")).Value`.

Comment: Yes I agree, the best would be an `With .... End With` statement to be sure that we are referring to the correct range/worksheet and avoid any implication of running the code :)

Comment: What BigBen means is that you could just write `ws.Cells(i, "K")`.

Comment: or `ws.Range("K" & i)`.

Comment: Yes, true! I didn't think about that in this case :). Personally the `ws.Cells(i, "K")` makes most sense :). I'm not a too big fan of Range... I have some experience that they sometimes bug/stop working :/